# Google App Script WebApp, Manipulating UI

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

Hi and Good day to all,

Google App Script can be used in so many  ways. I know cause I have tried some of them but Iam not an expert so, the situation is.

I have created an Spreadsheet
create a form using the new UI Building that comes with the script editor.
named:gtest01
UI compose of:

- label, id=label_caption
- button 1, id=button_hide, event-onmouseclick=hide_label
- button 2, id=button_show, event-onmouseclick=show_label
- button 3, id=button_message, event-onmouseclick=message_me

now, the code is:

```
/* This is so when I want to just deploy it as a [webapp] using the
script editor -> Publish Deploy as Web App
*/
function doGet(e) {
 var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("Sheet Application");
  app.add(app.loadComponent("gtest01"));
  Logger.log("Application UI Loaded");  
  return app;
}

function message_me(e) {  
  Browser.msgBox("my message"); 
}

function hide_label(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  label =app.getElementById("label_caption");
  label.setVisible(false);
}

function show_label(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  label =app.getElementById("label_caption");
  label.setVisible(true);
}

// this code is for when the spreadsheet is shared so they can access the form
function showform_() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  app.add(app.loadComponent("gtest01"));
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(app); 
}

function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [];
  menuEntries.push({name: "Show Form", functionName: "showform_"});
  ss.addMenu("e-Test", menuEntries);
}
```

First scenario is that when spreadsheet is shared

- when menu is clicked the form will load - thats good
- when show and hide button nothing happens - why and how can i fixed
  this?
- when message button is click - message will show but the form will
  close, how can I display a message without closing the form?

Second scenario is that when publish as Webapp.

- When Developer Link is Access the UI is always updated - ok
- When URL Link is Access the UI is always updated its like it is
  cache, how can I fixed this?
- on dev link: when show and hide button nothing happens - why and how
  can i fixed this?
- on dev link: when message button is click - will generate an error,
  how can I display an alert message on WebApp

Please help I have search and tried the sample codes and answer in the forum am missing something.

Thanks

Nick Ace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First scenario
when show and hide button nothing happens - why and how can i fixed this?

In your functions, use return app at the end. Unless you return the app object, the UI doesn't get updated.

how can I display a message without closing the form? - Try 
`SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast()`

2nd scenario

When URL Link is Access the UI is always updated its like it is cache, how can I fixed this? - Save your most recent code as a version

on dev link: when show and hide button nothing happens - Again return app will take care of this

on dev link: when message button is click... - Browser.msgBox is not supported in a web app.

Comment: Thanks Serge and Srik, I will try this later; this have been posted 2 day ago I wonder why stockoverflow does not sent mail notification? anyway, i will post my result so that it could somehow be helpfull for others. thanks

Answer (score 1):

When Using UI it is generally a good idea to make everything happen inside this Ui, so try to avoid showing messages with Toast( as they are not supported in web apps anyway).
Since you are using the GUI it should be quite easy to use a label with your message that is initially invisible and to make it visible in an handler routine.
Note that this kind of handler can be a client handler as well unless you need to do something else from this action.

As for the other points of you question, our (very fast) friend Srik has already answered thoroughly ;-)

Comment: yes the plan is to make everything in UI and spreadsheet as the backend, well, somehow.thnks